# Creating summary text layer like realestate.com.au using CartoDB?

Tags: carto, carto-js

I've been playing around with the cartodb platform and haven't been able to find out how to create a data summary or view of the averages for given location. I see that the team at realestate.com.au managed to do it. But I'm not sure how.

Any ideas?

[image: realestate.com.au example]

Answer (score 1):

If the layer has the "summary" information you want to show, is possible. So this means that for each feature/polygon (row) has a field (column) for "Annual Growth", another for "Median price" and so on. As I have explained [in another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185450/how-to-make-a-fixed-block-of-text-in-cartodb-instead-of-infowindows), there are two steps to follow in order to generate  with CartoDB.js a fixed infobox to display that information as the example you have shared. First, create a div within your html template and then a "click event" function to associate the data from the selected feature with that div.